# ruby mock http request but the server can not get header

Tags: ruby, http

my ruby CODE below:

```
require "net/http"
require "open-uri"

require "uri"

@agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.65 Safari/537.31'
data = {"m"=>"user", "a"= >"login", "release"=>"20110501", "appid"=>"3"};

uri = URI.parse("url")
request = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, data)

request.initialize_http_header({"USER-AGENT" => "asdsdsd"})
puts request.class
puts request.body
```

server CODE below：

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']."\n";
?>
```

need your help,some one can help me, thanks so much?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I cannot get header contents from server,such as USER_AGENT,but now I got the answer,thanks for your your attention

Answer (score 0):

finnally I got answer from my leader and ruby-china.org 
then I change something and it works for me now

```
require "net/http"
require "open-uri"
require "uri"

@agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.65 Safari/537.31'
data = {"m"=>"user", "a" =>"login", "release"=>"20110501", "appid"=>"3"};

uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:8080/server/uc.php")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.set_form_data(data)
request.initialize_http_header({"USER-AGENT" => @agent})

response = http.request(request)
puts response.body
```